# Writing a VBA makro to sum a nested bill of materials

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have looked around extensively on the web but have not been able to find a way to calculate a nested table of totals.

My data is pictured below.

[image: Nested Bom]

What I am looking for is a way to add up all of the sub items of an item and put that total in the cost of the original item.

so for instance the total of line 6 will be the sum of lines 7,8,9, and 10. but the total of line 2 will be the totals of lines 5,6,11, and 12 each of which needs to be seperatly subtotalled.

I have tried excels subtotal function, but it is clumsy and not a generalised solution. I may need to add or subtract components over time and have the totals calculated again.

I have tried a few if then and for loop combinations, as well as an attempt at a function that calls itsself, with very limited success.

I think I have a block in how to approach this, as well as some programming knowledge gaps, like can a function call its self, and if it does, will it automatically create an independant set of function instance variables, or will the new call overwrite the old instances variables.

Any help with methodology and knowledge would be great.

Thanks

Comment: `tried a few if then and for loop combinations` please show your code

Comment: What about `SumIfs()`? On line 6, you want to sum `1.1.2.1, .2, .3, and .4` why not use a sumif saying like `=SumIf(B2:B100,b6,D2:D100)`? (Basically have it look for 1.1.2.* and then sum that?

Comment: @BruceWayne you would need to add a check to make sure it is only summing the next step, as in, with 1.1 we want 1.1.1,1.1.2 but not 1.1.2.1.  You can do that with len().  but you would then need to move it into a sumproduct instead of a sumif().

Comment: @ScottCraner - "...then need to move it into a sumproduct instead...", whelp, then I'm out! (I really need to get a handle on `Sumproduct`, as it appears all the time in your answers (and @Jeeped) and it looks very versatile.)

Comment: @ScottCraner quit your drooling over the sumproduct possibility...I think you dropped your glasses in that wet concrete the other day with that extra 79 in the last question! 8)

Comment: @BruceWayne  Wrap your head aroun CSE formulas first,  then its usually just one or two more steps to the sumproduct/aggregate options.

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work for you? In a new column, say E, starting in E3 and copied down:

```
=SUM(IF(LEFT(B3:B$999,LEN(B3))=B3,D3:D$999,0))
```

Here `999` is a dummy last row --- change it to suit your situation.

Columns B and D are assumed to hold `Outline` and `Bom Cost`, respectively. The logic is: sum up all rows below (and including) the current row *if and only if* `Outline` starts like the current row's `Outline`. So if `Outline` in the current row is 1.2.3 it sums up all `Bom Costs` found below where `Outline` start with 1.2.3 (1.2.3.1, 1.2.3.2, 1.2.3.2.1, etc.).

This formula assumes that the outline is properly ordered.

It is also assumed that the `Outline` values are text. If they are not, the formula above will fail when `Outline` is a whole number (1, 2, ...). This longer formula converts whole numbers to text and should work:

```
=SUM(IF(LEFT(B3:B$999,LEN(B3))=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3,".",""))<LEN(B3),B3,TEXT(B3,"0")),D3:D$999,0))
```

Hope this helps.